# Adding Administrator user on application boot in Grails

Tags: grails, deployment, bootstrapping

I am wondering how to add Administrator user to a Grails app on the boot.

**Scenario:** I developed Grails application and have User permission in place (implemented in Grails). Now once I deploy app on a server, the very first thing it should do is to create Admin user. My question is how to do it? I don't need elaborate "installation" right now.

**My thoughts:** I figured to put check and admin creation code in bootstrap, here is a sample code:

```
def admin = User.findByLogin("admin")
if (!admin) {
   admin = new User(login:"admin", name:"Administrator", password:"password")
   admin.save()
}
```

However everytime I run app in eclipse it fails to do anything. I mean no errors, no movement at all. Application runs fine but it seems like bootstrap is skipped completely.

Question is how do I add Admin user via Grails app on a first run or a boot?
If I need to use a bootstrap, what is an issue with my above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely the case that the `save()` call is failing to validate. Replace `admin.save()` with

```
if (!admin.save()) {
    println "Failed to save admin due to errors: $admin.errors"
}
```

or something similar to get an indication of what's going on. Also add another println before this code to ensure that the code is even running - you may have a more significant error in the code.

In general it's best to run `grails clean` when code that should work doesn't. It forces a full recompilation and often makes weird behavior go away.

Comment: Here is my code and it doesn't produce any output into console:
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
  log.error "Hello BootStrap"
  println "println BootStrap"
    }
    def destroy = {
  
    }
}

Comment: I figured it out. 
1. Application was loading a while after it started. Probably due to few plugins in the project.
2. Quartz started and couldn't see much ( large amount of logs ).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
def admin = User.findByLogin("admin")
if (!admin) {
   admin = new User(login:"admin", name:"Administrator", password:"password")
   admin.save(failOnError:true)
}
```

The flag **failOnError** force grails to throw exception if save was unsuccessful due to validation errors, without this flag grails will not save instance silently.